# Finding all the lists of lenght n with only 1s and 0 in Python

Tags: python, list, combinations, combinatorics

I'm stuck on a question that should be an easy one but I can't possibly solve.
Given an integer n, I need to find all the possible combinations of lists that contain only 1s and 0s.
For example , with  n=3,  the  answer is:`[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,0]`
if I'm not missing any.
I found that we can find this number of lists adding 1 and 0 to all lists of lenght  n-1 following this condition. I then made this function:

```
def ensemble_liste(n):
if n==1:
    return [[1],[0]] 
return [[0]+ensemble_liste(n-1),[1]+ensemble_liste(n-1)]]
```

But it's returning me a syntax error  on the second return. Formatting it like this

```
return [[[0]+ensemble_liste(n-1)],[[1]+ensemble_liste(n-1)]]
```

works , but  I get the  following output with n=3(it's a list made of two elements )

```
[[0, [[0, [1], [0]]], [[1, [1], [0]]]]]#First element
[[1, [[0, [1], [0]]], [[1, [1], [0]]]]]#Second element
```

which isn't quite formatted like I would like and it is giving an incorrect answer...
Does anyone has an idea on how to correct this ?
Thank you very much

Comment: Not exactly  as the answers given doesn't have the formatting I needed , but I think I can adapt them. Thank you  very  much !

Comment: @RoadRunner, from itertools, it will be easy, I think we need to help using recursion

Comment: @Francesco what formatting do you expect exactly?

Comment: @AjinkyaTaranekar Why do you need recursion? Itertools or bit manipulation are alot easier.

Comment: @RoadRunner his question involve recursion, so, that's why.